# How to store the data metrics collected from Zabbix agent in milliseconds resolution instead of minutes resolution

Tags: monitoring, zabbix

I want different data metrics like CPU utilization, memory utilization from Zabbix agent with milliseconds resolution instead of minutes resolution.

I am using `Zabbix Python API` to retrieve metrics from Mysql Zabbix database and noticed that data is stored with minutes resolution, which is as shown below:

```
Sl.NO Date                            Value

 1   Monday, March 25, 2019 04:22:07  0.0700
 2   Monday, March 25, 2019 04:23:07  0.0600
 3   Monday, March 25, 2019 04:24:07  0.1400
 4   Monday, March 25, 2019 04:25:07  0.2700
 5   Monday, March 25, 2019 04:26:07  0.2400
 6   Monday, March 25, 2019 04:27:07  0.1800
 7   Monday, March 25, 2019 04:28:07  0.1600
 8   Monday, March 25, 2019 04:29:07  0.1700
 9   Monday, March 25, 2019 04:30:07  0.0600
 10  Monday, March 25, 2019 04:31:07  0.0600
 11  Monday, March 25, 2019 04:32:07  0.1300
```

Is it possible in Zabbix to store the data metrics with milliseconds (or nanoseconds) resolution. If yes, how should I do that.

Answer (score 1):

Data is retrieved and stored according to the *Update interval* defined on the item, which is 60 seconds in your example.

You can't have an update interval lesser that 1 second, see the [documentation](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/4.0/manual/config/items/item):

> Update interval:  Retrieve a new value for this item every N seconds

As a consideration, I've always used update intervals in the order of minutes, with 30 seconds for specific situations.

A more frequent update interval is usually an overkill if not an "auto-DoS", let's make an **unreal** example: reading 1000 values per second from 10 hosts means 10000 inserts into the database per second, with 10000 * 86400 * 90 bytes of storage per day (see [here](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/4.0/manual/installation/requirements))... and then you have to read and analyze this huge amount of data!

And of course I'm not considering the load on the Zabbix Agents, the servers will be crushed under the load of the monitoring system.

Plan really carefully your update intervals, both in term of Agent load and Server load, IOPS capacity of your storage, data retention etc... The [requirement](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/4.0/manual/installation/requirements) documentation covers them in detail.

Comment: (1) Is it possible to collect some of the 1000 metrics (let's say 100 metrics) from 1 host and insert in the database for retrieving data metrics less than 1 second. (2) I already noticed that the time format is UNIX timestamp, but I noticed some forums citing the reason of `nanosecond` column in history for collecting metrics less than 1 second.

Comment: Of course you can insert 1000 new values per seconds or even more, you just need a storage wich supports enough IOPS, like a nice SSD raid.